# How to make a symlink to an AppImage

Tags: symbolic-link, appimage

I am trying to create a symlink to be able to run a newer version of qpdf than the one installed in 18.04.

They provide a AppImage.

if I do:

```
/usr/local/bin$ sudo wget https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/releases/download/release-qpdf-9.1.1/qpdf-9.1.1-x86_64.AppImage
/usr/local/bin$ sudo chmod a+x qpdf-9.1.1-x86_64.AppImage
/usr/local/bin$ ./qpdf-9.1.1-x86_64.AppImage --version
qpdf version 9.1.1
Run qpdf --copyright to see copyright and license information.
```

But when I try to do a symlink (so I can call it as qpdf anywhere):

```
/usr/local/bin$ sudo ln -s qpdf-9.1.1-x86_64.AppImage qpdf
/usr/local/bin$ ./qpdf --version

qpdf: an input file name is required

Usage: qpdf [options] infile outfile
For detailed help, run qpdf --help
```

And it doesn't show the version (or `--help`, etc).

How can I make it work?

*I am new to Linux and maybe I am missing something obvious.*

Answer (score 1):

I've done it in the next way:

- `mkdir ~/appimage && cd ~/appimage`
- `wget https://github.com/qpdf/qpdf/releases/download/release-qpdf-9.1.1/qpdf-9.1.1-x86_64.AppImage`
- `chmod +x ~/appimage/qpdf-9.1.1-x86_64.AppImage`
- `$ vim.tiny appimage/qpdf.sh`

  ```
  #!/bin/bash
  cd /home/user/appimage/ && exec ./qpdf-9.1.1-x86_64.AppImage "$@"`
  ```
- `chmod +x ~/appimage/qpdf.sh`
- `sudo ln -s /home/user/appimage/qpdf.sh /usr/local/bin/qpdf`

As a result:

```
$ qpdf --version
qpdf version 9.1.1
Run qpdf --copyright to see copyright and license information.
```

Comment: I would advise against this because you essentially make an executable file in `/usr/local/bin` writable by a user other than root. However, you could create the symlink in `~/bin`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to disable parameters:

```
./qpdf -- --version
```

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't directly answer your question about symlinking, but here is another approach you can try.

#### Uninstall qpdf

`apt remove qpdf`

#### Make a custom desktop launcher for the AppImage

`nano ~/.local/share/applications/qpdf.desktop`

In ~/.local/share/applications/ create the launcher, customizing the "Exec" path here to match the location of your AppImage file.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Name=qpdf
Exec=Path/To/Your/qpdf.AppImage
Terminal=false
X-MultipleArgs=false
Type=Application
StartupNotify=true
```

#### Add the qpdf command to .bashrc for CLI use

`nano ~/.bashrc && source ~/.bashrc`

Paste the following lines at the end of your existing ~/.bashrc file. As above, customize the path in this example to match the location of your AppImage file.

```
qpdf()
{
~/Path/To/Your/qpdf.AppImage
}
```

Comment: Creating the desktop launcher for the AppImage works, but not able to run it, am i missing anything?
(I am able to run the AppImage through sh)

Comment: @GajendraJena You may need to log out & log back in for the desktop launcher. Also double-check the path is correct. Is it still not working afterwards? Also, which AppImage are you using, qpdf or something else?